# What is the deceleration if the rear-wheel brakes are disabled?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, physics

An automobile is braking on a flat, dry road with a coefficient of static friction of 0.90 between its wheels and the road. The wheelbase (the distance
between the front and the rear wheels) is 3.0 m, and the center of mass is midway between the wheels, at a height of 0.60 m above the road.

What is the deceleration if the rear-wheel brakes are disabled? Take
into account that during braking, the normal force on the front wheels
is larger than that on the rear wheels.

I was trying:

$$\Sigma F_X = f_r+f_f = ma$$
$$\Sigma f_Y = N_f+N_r=mg$$
$$\Sigma \tau = ma(0.6)+N_F(1.5)+N_r(1.5)+f_r(1.5)+f_f(1.5)$$

where the sub f and sub r represent the rear and the front wheels components of normal and friction respectively

solving for a in the 3 equation

$$ma(0.6) = 1.5(mg)+1.5(ma)$$
$$a = \frac{1.5}{2.1}g$$

however this answer IS WRONG can someone tell me what I get wrong?

Comment: note when the car is braking the chasis of the front part moves down thats why I say there is a torque

Comment: I can't speak to the correctness of your torque equation, but purely from a mathematical perspective, you missed a sign change when you moved the $1.5(ma)$ term to the left.

Comment: still the answer is wrong

Comment: If you're calculating the torque about the center of mass, shouldn't the $f_r$ and $f_f$ be multiplied by $0.6$ instead of $1.5$?

Comment: I try that but is still wrong the answer hsould be around 5.3

Comment: $f_r=0$ since the brakes are disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that **the rear brakes are disabled**. So the friction force on the rear is zero. Then $$f_f=0.9N_f=ma\\N_r+N_f=mg$$
For the torque equation, write it around the point of contact of the front wheel with the road (the torque of $N_f$ and $f_f$ are zero):
$$3N_r+0.6ma-1.5mg=0$$
Taking $N_f=ma/0.9$from the first equation, we get $$N_r=mg-\frac{ma}{0.9}$$
Plug this into the torque equation:
$$3mg-\frac{ma}{0.3}+0.6ma-1.5mg=0\\1.5mg=ma\left(\frac1{0.3}-0.6\right)\\1.5g=a2.733\\a=\frac{1.5}{2.733}g=0.548g=0.548\cdot 9.8m/s^2=5.37m/s^2$$

Comment: thank you sir...

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: why is that if the rear brakes are disabled there is no friction?

Comment: They mentioned static friction. That can happen only when the wheels are locked. If the brakes are disabled, the wheels are rolling. The rolling friction is much less. One can push a car in neutral. Even if only one of the breaks are working, pushing a typical 2000 kg car is equivalent of lifting 450 kg. The Olympic records are just slightly more than 200 kg.